# How do I add navigations to an iOS UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I'm very new to iOS programming and am relatively unfamiliar with how swift works. I've been trying to make a basic app that displays a webpage and I need to a navigation bar (preferably at the bottom) that has at least a back button and forward button. My storyboard just contains a fullsize webview.

Here is my View Controller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://71republic.com/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        WebView.load(request)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What you want to achieve with navigation ? Is it navigation through the web content ? Or within the apps ?

Comment: through web content. The site opens links withtin the webview so i dont need mutliple views

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
1st: If you want navigation bar at the bottom, drag navigation bar from items to bottom of your view controller.

2nd: Put your view controller into navigation path. You should add Navigation controller into your storyboard and make your controller root view controller.

For 'back' button you should have previous page and navigate to your current page with segue. And for 'Next' you should navigate your current page to next page with segue.

Read about segue, navigation bar, navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks! Just added a navigation bar. As a follow up question, do you know how to set the title as an image?

Comment: @JJefferson implement viewDidAppear() like what did this link do: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-navigation-bar-ios-tutorial-ios10

Answer (score 0):

This is what your looking for my friend : [How To Create A Web Browser In Xcode 8 (Swift 3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzNJfMzjOkQ)